# While loop int does not update

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a script that scrapes a website, but the while loop does not work. The script downloads a website and then checks if it is a website or a image.
If the downloaded item is a HTML file it saves it and adds 1 to i and the URL.

Problem: The URL does not change, even tho I think it should with this code.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 5)
{
    using var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "C# console program");

    int urlnumb = 1;
    string url = "http://localhost:7211/database/resource/pk/" + urlnumb;
    string content = client.DownloadString(url);
    string htmldefiner = "html";

    if (content.Contains(htmldefiner))
    {
        string savedirectory = @"C:/Temp/" + i + ".html";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savedirectory, content);
        i++;
        urlnumb++;
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:/Temp/" + i + ".txt", url);
    }
    else
    {
        urlnumb++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: You mean that `int urlnumb = 1;` that exists solely for the lifetime of a single iteration of the loop? You might want to move it outside the scope of the loop if you want it to live for longer. (Note: I'm not talking about garbage collection when I say "exists" or "live")

Comment: Take a closer look at your code. Think about variable scopes. What is the difference between how and where you initialize i and urlnumb?

Comment: Thanks for your help, after i moved the int out of the loop everything worked as intendet.